# How to edit element in row by double clicking "in meteor"

Tags: javascript, meteor, bootstrap-modal

I want to open bootstrap modal by double clicking to the element in the row to be able to edit it.

[image: first]

[image]

Lets say **when I double click the Name(Nuriddinhon), modal view should open with that Nuriddinhon, and I should be able to edit this name.**

Here is my js file:

```
Template.projectRow.events({
    'dblclick .projectRow':function(evt,tmpl) {
        Session.set('editing_project', tmpl.data._id);
    //what should be here?
    }
});
```

And html file:

```
<template name="projects">

{{>projectForm}}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">Project
                <small>List</small>
            </h1>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success addProject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button">Add project</button>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-stiped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Client</th>
                    <th>Due Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {{#each projectList}}
            {{>projectRow}}
            {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<template name="projectRow">
<tr class="projectRow">
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{client}}</td>
    <td>{{formatDate duedate}}</td>
    <td>{{status}}</td>
</tr>
```

```
<template name="projectForm">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add project</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control name" value="{{project.name}}" title="" required="" >
                      <label for="client">Client:</label><input type="text" name="client" id="client" class="form-control client" value="{{project.client}}" title="" required="" >
                      <label for="status">Status:</label>
                      <select class="form-control status" name="status" id="status">
                          <option value="OnHold">On Hold</option>
                          <option value="Active">Active</option>
                      </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I think I could explain my wish, sorry for my language mistakes :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can achive this easy, using [Blaze.renderWithData](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_renderwithdata) method.

Lets say you have a template like this.

```
<template name="myModalToEdit">
 {{! Modal Content }}
</template>
```

and then you can simple call this modal like this.

```
Template.projectRow.events({
    'dblclick .projectRow':function(evt,tmpl) {
      dataToModal = {
       id: tmpl.data._id
     };
      Blaze.renderWithData(Template.myModalToEdit, dataToModal, document.body)
    }
});
```

Now with this you will need to add inside the `.js` of the `myModalToEdit` template the following code inside the [onRendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) method.

```
Templae.myModalToEdit.onRendered(function(){ 
  var tmpl = this;

  $('#modal-selector').modal(); //Launch the modal

  console.log(tmpl.data); // should the print the data passed on dataToModal Variable
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `data-toggle="modal"` change it to:

```
data-toggle="dbl-modal"
```

And in the jQuery, if you have a `document`s `ready` function, add this:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '[data-toggle="dbl-modal"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr("href")).modal("show");
});
```

Let me know if it works. You can either add this to your `bootstrap.min.js` or your custom JavaScript file.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
$(document).on('dblclick', '[data-toggle="dbl-modal"]', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr("href")).modal("show");
});
```

```css
body {padding: 25px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<a href="#modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dbl-modal">Double Click</a>
<a href="#modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Click</a>
```